# What's the theory of add a `'` after query number for SQL Inject test?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

One SQL inject way is like this:
add a `'` after query number param:

```
http://www.demo.com/cates?id=1'
```

but why? what's the theory of it?

---

**EDIT-01**

I tried a query with `'` but there only stop and waiting more instruct, there is no error report.

```
mysql> select * from ask_user_tags where id=1';
    '> 
    '> 
    '> Ctrl-C -- exit!
Aborted
```

why the `'` can judge?

Comment: In most cases, parameters are replacing strings and `'` terminates the string.  That allows additional code to follow the completed string.  You should be aware that this is only one method of injecting SQL.  And the right solution is to use parameterized queries to insert such values.

Comment: A single quote is only supposed to check if there's any suspicious difference in the behavior (errors, unexpected results etc) before starting with more sophisticated options.

Comment: Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see an example:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username';`
If there is no ' in $username, the SQL have a syntax error.
But if the given value is
`';DELETE FROM users; --`
there is no syntax error, and the query runs.